# Conditional border color

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I would like to set the border-color of an item depending on its category. I tried using [ngStyle] and style.color but it doesn't work. 
Can someone help me ?

```
<ion-grid *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="openDetail(item)" [style.color]=" api.getCategoryColor(item.categories[0])">
```

Thank you

Edit : 
it works when setting color "blue" for example :

```
<ion-row [style.border]="'solid 1px ' + 'blue'" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the border color with:

```
[style.border-color]="api.getCategoryColor(item.categories[0])"
```

Make sure that a border is always present, for example with a class style:

```
<ion-grid class="gridBorder" ...>
```

```
.gridBorder {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

or by binding the border style itself, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50897357/1009922) by [@fatemefazli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8990367/fateme-fazli).

---

If you need to use SCSS variables, you can bind a style class to the element:

```
<ion-grid class="gridBorder" [ngClass]="api.getCategoryClass(item.categories[0])" ... >
```

and set the border color with SCSS variables in each class:

```
.cat1 {
  border-color: $cat1_Color;
}

.cat2 {
  border-color: $cat2_color;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer but it doesn't work neither :(

Comment: In a comment to the other answer, you say that it works when you set the color to `blue`. Can you show in the question how you make it work with the blue color?

Comment: I added an alternative method, with class names.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I don't know why but it doesn't work when using api.getCategoryColor. I've tried with my variables name that are in variables.scss and none works. The only way to make it work is to set colors in hex

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
[style.border]=" '1px solid '+ api.getCategoryColor(item.categories[0])"
```

check this working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cpjlr3)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. It works but it doesn't work when I use an SCSS variable name. Anyway thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure if this `CSS` setting is applied to `ion-grid` or the actual DOM element that will reflect the color change. Normally component itself is just a `<div>` element.

What you could do is to first find that element, and just apply CSS directly to it as a first test. If it works, then you have options to either wrapping that CSS in your own component, or leaving that CSS in your global style sheet. Either way is manageable.

Comment: It works when setting color like "blue" but not with api.getCategoryColor(item.categories[0])

Comment: then you need to `console.log` `api.getCategoryColor` and make sure if item.categories[0] is populated. Maybe it's better to first define a function to wrap it, ex. `getColor() { this.api.getCategoryColor() }`